# Get values from a JSON array API request

Tags: c#, arrays, json, parsing

Having a structure of JSON like this:

```
[
0, 
1, 
2, 
3
]
```

Returned by API webclient call, how do I get those values and make them useable?

My code is like this at the moment:

```
myJSON = client.DownloadString(URL);
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int>>(json);

if (result.key = 2)
{
    //VALUE FOUND, DO SOMETHING WITH IT
}
```

However, it just doesn't work

Comment: Dictionary<int> ? This is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is not a dictionary but a list of int.

`List<int>()`

Change it to this:

```
myJSON = client.DownloadString(URL); 
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(json); 

var value = result.Where(r => r == 2).FirstOrDefault();

if (value != null) { 
//VALUE FOUND, DO SOMETHING WITH IT 
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. One more question, how do I check all the contents of the array, not knowing which values it output? for example, on result[2] not always is a value of 2, it may be 3, 5, 10 etc. So if I want to "find" the number 2 or any other numbers in the array, is that possible?

Comment: You can use linq for that, something like this, var value = result.Where(r => r == 2).FirstOrDefault();. Ill update my answer.

Comment: I just tried to fix the code now with your suggestions, but this is what I get: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'API.Find'

Comment: What is API.Find? Its not in the code you provided.

Comment: it is another class used to deserialize another request on the same file, i'll update my question

Comment: nevermind! it's because the variable result were used for the other API call before, so it was attempting to use the API.Find class. Changing the variable into another name, now it works.! I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: one last question sorry, how do i make something like a switch/case for example: switch(result)  case 1: do something if there is 1 in array; case 2: do something if there is 2; case 3: etc etc ?

Comment: That is not how switches work. You can only work on one value on a switch. What you can do is create a loop. Then inside the loop, add a switch.